# Is there a way to get certain attributes of HTML elements using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

So I want to fetch some data from certain HTML elements. I know that there is a way to fetch `innerText` and `innerHTML` but when I have an HTML element like this:

```html
<span id="example" name="example">example</span>
```

Is there a way to get the name with JavaScript so basically:

```js
document.getElementById('example').name
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes I googled your question title

Comment: `document.getElementById('example').getAttribute("name")`

Comment: @trincot I can't research that well since my understanding of JavaScript and HTML is very basic. I just don't know what to search for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why `document.getElementById('example').name` does not work is because the result of `getElementById` is a DOM element, not an object.

So using the [getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) method on it will do.

```js
let test = document.getElementById('example').getAttribute("name")
console.log(test)
```

```html
<span id="example" name="AttributeName">example</span>
```

Instead of just Googling, when looking for a method like that, use the search field of the [MDN website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web) ;)